# How would my WEB APP knows which username is accessing it?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, web-applications, web

My web app take data from XML file and manipulate it.I want to make my app dynamic so that it only access the data of the particular user which is accessing the app.Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Use **System Property** to get user name.

```
public class UserName {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String username;
   username = System.getProperty("user.name");
   System.out.println(username);
   }
}
```

In Perl/CGI,

```
my $user = getpwuid($<);
```

In C#

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

Which language are you using ?

Comment: I didn't know about c#. Added C# in your question tag to make it more clear.

Comment: You can use WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name